# How to auto transmission in android

Tags: android, object, gson

I have an User class

```
public class User implements Parcelable {
private String user_id;
private String username;
private String fullname;
private String workplace;
private String p_re_ward;
private String p_re_district;
private String p_re_province;
private String p_so_ward;
private String p_so_district;
private String p_so_province;
private String p_bi_ward;
private String p_bi_district;
private String p_bi_province;
private String p_place_of_birth_id;
private String p_identity_issue_place_id;
private String usercode;
private String usercode_old;
private String image;
private String front_identity_card;
private String back_identity_card;
private String portrait;
private String signature;
private String images;
private String email;
private String telephone;
private String gender;
private String p_identity_number;
private String p_identity_issue_date;
private String p_identity_issue_place;
private String p_tax_code;
private String p_insurance_num;
private String p_belonging_persons;
private String p_relative_telephone;
private String p_birthday;
private String p_place_of_birth;
private String p_nationality;
private String p_nation;
private String p_degree;
private String p_re_address;
private String p_re_province_id;
private String p_re_district_id;
private String p_re_ward_id;
private String p_so_address;
private String p_so_province_id;
private String p_so_district_id;
private String p_bi_address;
private String p_bi_province_id;
private String p_bi_district_id;
private String p_bi_ward_id;
private String p_protector;
private String p_bank_holder;
private String p_bank_number;
private String p_bank_name;
private String user_group_id;
private String province_id;
private String district_id;
private String ward_id;
private String address;
private String latitude;
private String longitude;
public int status;


public void setUserId(String user_id){
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public String getUserId(){
    return this.user_id;
}

public void setUsername(String username){
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUsername(){
    return this.username;
}

public void setFullname(String fullname){
    this.fullname = fullname;
}

public String getFullname(){
    return this.fullname;
}


public static final Parcelable.Creator<User> CREATOR = new Creator<User>() {
    public User createFromParcel(Parcel p) {
        return new User(p);
    }
    public User[] newArray(int size) {
        return new User[size];
    }
};

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
    parcel.writeString(user_id);
    parcel.writeString(username);
    parcel.writeString(fullname);
}

private User(Parcel p){
    setUserId(p.readString());
    setUsername(p.readString());
    setFullname(p.readString());
}
```

}

I use Gson convert json to Object success.

I need auto transmission all params to main_activity. Now i can transmission each params but it very lengthy.

Can i convert to array like php? Or how to shrink this?

Sory bad english

Comment: What does mean by `transmission`?

Comment: i mean is automatically assigns all data. now i use function setUsername, setUserId... to assign data. but i have more than 30 fields, i need a solution to add faster

Comment: use constructor with default value

Comment: sorry i don't understand, can you show example?

Comment: I have created gist have look at that https://gist.github.com/milaptank/87ca83a3c8c499ac1b146e88b5ec4324  this is using builder pattern

Comment: thanks MilapTank. One more question. can i include all params to array and loop it? and how if can

Comment: yes you can use like User.Builder().fullname("").address("").build();

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: if you have helped then i will put as answer let me know

Comment: have you skype? can you add my skype?

Comment: don't worry. i just find new friends. thanks